# fix repeating "enter names of teacher" after I finish the input?

Tags: c++

this code should record school data names and address but after input it repeats "enter names of teachers:" line several times before the output of data entered successfully how can i fix this problem? any tweaks in the code to achieve this? it should be school projects in C++ but I can't fix this problem at all I would apprecciate any help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string sname, saddress, sname_teacher;
    int snumber_classrooms;
    double ratio, snumber_students, snumber_teachers;
    //Entering data of school
    cout << "Enter school data: \n";
    cout << "Enter name of school : ";
    cin >> sname;
    cout << "Enter an address of school : ";
    cin >> saddress;
    cout << "Enter number of classrooms of the school : ";
    cin >> snumber_classrooms;
    cout << "Enter number of students of the school : ";
    cin >> snumber_students;
    cout << "Enter number of teachers of the school : ";
    cin >> snumber_teachers;
    //check if  number of teachers < 20 or not
    if (snumber_teachers > 20) {
        while (snumber_teachers > 20) {
            cout << " The number of teachers should not be more than 20 teachers. \n";
            cout << "Enter number of teachers of the school : ";
            cin >> snumber_teachers;
        }
    }
    //check if  number of teachers :  number of students < (1/50=0.02)
    ratio = snumber_teachers / snumber_students;
    while (ratio < 0.02) {
        cout << " The number of teachers should not be less than 1/50 number of students. \n";
        cout << "Enter number of teachers of the school : ";
        cin >> snumber_teachers;
        ratio = snumber_teachers / snumber_students;
    }
    // Entering names of teachers
    int snumber_teachers2 = snumber_teachers;
    stack<string> names;
    for (int i = 0; i < snumber_teachers2; i++) {
        cout << "Enter names of teachers : ";
        cin >> sname_teacher;
        names.push(sname_teacher);
    }
    cout << " \n The Data of shool has entered succedly :)\n \n";
    // Printing data of school
    cout << " _______________________The Data of school are_______________________ \n";
    cout << " name : " + sname << endl;
    cout << " address " + saddress << endl;
    cout << " classrooms  : " << snumber_classrooms << endl;
    cout << " students  : " << snumber_students << endl;
    cout << " teachers  : " << snumber_teachers << endl;
    cout << " names of teachers :  \n";
    // Printing content of stack
    while (!names.empty()) {
        cout << ' ' << names.top();
        names.pop();
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read a good C++ book, learn about conditionals, loops and then return to this.

Comment: I am a student and this is a project so I have limited knowledge in C++, Sure I will learn more but for now I am stuck with this with no time to learn

Comment: The problem with this code is that there is no problem. "Enter names" will appear as many times as the "number of teachers", which looks fine to me. If you don't want this, just remove the loop where it is asking for input.

Comment: I need the input but just one time to enter input of all names, can you point out which part exactly?

Comment: You want several teacher name inputs but only once "Enter names of teachers:" ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to receive several inputs for teacher names, but only prompt "Enter names of teachers : " once.

So change

```
for (int i = 0; i < snumber_teachers2; i++) {
    cout << "Enter names of teachers : ";
    cin >> sname_teacher;
    names.push(sname_teacher);
}
```

to

```
cout << "Enter names of teachers : ";
for (int i = 0; i < snumber_teachers2; i++) {
    cin >> sname_teacher;
    names.push(sname_teacher);
}
```

I.e. keep what you want to repeat inside the loop,
but move what you only want once outside.